# ¿ Recoger evento en servidor de boton html creado dinamicamente desde el propio servidor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017

Tengo un código en HTML con un botón que agrego dentro de un elemento 'DIV' dinámicamente desde el servidor.

¿ Como puedo saber desde el servidor que ese botón ha sido pulsado ?

Este es mi código en un archivo .aspx

```
<div id="miCodigo" runat="server">
</div>
```

y este es el código en el archivo .aspx.cs

```
// Dentro del Page_Load
string contenido = "";
contenido += "<button id='btn01' type='button' runat='server' onServerClick='miBoton_Click' />
miCodigo.InnerHtml = contenido;

// Función fuera del Page_Load que debería capturar el evento pero no lo hace
protected void miBoton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Mas codigo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No funciona de esa forma magicamente, si querias un boton que realice un evento debes crearlo desde codigo y definir un `Panel`, o sea

En el html debes definir un Panel de asp.net

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" id="miCodigo" />
```

Para crear el boton usarias

```
 Button btn1 = new Button();
 btn1.Click += miBoton_Click;

 miCodigo.Controls.Add(btn1);
```

Entonces si tendras el evento ya que se trata de controles de asp.net generados dinamicamente

Lo que comento esta documentado

[Cómo: Crear dinámicamente controles en ASP.NET utilizando .NET Visual C#](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/317794/how-to-dynamically-create-controls-in-asp-net-by-using-visual-c-net)

---

Si quieres que el boton sea `html` entonces los `eventos de asp.net` ya no aplican, vas a tener que usar `ajax`, es mas facl si lo haces por medio de `jquery` para invocar en el `click` del boton en el browser un `WebMethod` en el servidor.

[Calling ASP.Net WebMethod using jQuery AJAX](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx)

veras como utiliza

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "CS.aspx/GetCurrentTime",
    data: '{name: "' + $("#<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: OnSuccess,
    failure: function(response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});
```

para invocar el webmethod

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetCurrentTime(string name)
{
    return "Hello " + name + Environment.NewLine + "The Current Time is: "
        + DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Con esto en el click de un boton pero usando `onclick` que es el evento en javascript

Comment: Estoy usando asp en codebehind.  En vez del panel tengo un form y dentro el div al que agrego el código. He creado un botón HTML con HtmlButton btn1 = new HtmlButton() pero no me acepta el btn1.Click pero si un btn1.ServerClick pero no me acaba de funcionar.

Comment: El otro ejemplo que pones con Ajax y webmethod creo que esta indicado para asp con MVC y no asp codebehind. ¿ Me equivoco ? Lo digo porque entonces el Ajax lo puedo substituir por un __doPostback. Pero aun asi, lo que estoy buscando es primero añadir el código desde el servidor y asignar los eventos también desde el servidor no asignar eventos desde el cliente

Comment: en que evento defines este codigo? porque olvide remrcar que solo funciona si el boton dinamico lo creas en los evento Init de la pagina ya que tiene que recrearse el boton en cada evento

Comment: no ajax y webemthod es para asp.net (no revisaste el link del ejemplo, ali se usa asp.net), para asp.net mvc se usa ajax pero directo a los action del controller

Comment: El código lo inserto en el PageLoad del servidor y luego de hacer el InnerHtml asigno el evento del botón también en el PageLoad

Comment: no aplica ningun InnerHtml, porque esto es el render del control, deberias usar el Controls.Add(), sino no aplican los eventos del lado del servidor

Comment: No lo acabo de entender. Lo que necesito es insertar código desde el servidor dentro de un div y si tiene algún botón este código insertado que llame a la función del servidor asignada. Los eventos tengo que asignarlos también desde el servidor porque el cliente no va a saber cuantos y  que elementos responderán a eventos

Comment: Y el evento que intento asignar lo hago desde el PageLoad

Comment: Es que asp.net no funciona de forma magica cuando creas codigo dinamico debes seguir ciertas reglas, debes usar controles de asp.net no controles de html, debes poner el codigo en el evento Init de la pagina para que los eventos respondan, por eso es que recomiendo usar ajax si la idea es usar html dinamico

Comment: edite la respuesta y agregue un link donde se documenta esto que estos comentando

Comment: Necesito usar elementos HTML para que sea compatible con HTML5 y CSS3. De momento me ha ido funcionando todo bien con elementos HTML usando runat="server". Seguire haciendo pruebas con lo que me dices del evento Init de la pagina

Comment: pero si necesitas que sea html entonces porque no puedes usar ajax para invocar al servidor? porque tiene que ser un evento de asp.net

Comment: En principio lo que deseo no es usar Ajax para invocar al servidor ni _doPostback . Lo que estaba buscando era asignar el evento desde el servidor. Pero si lo tuviera que hacer si uso _doPostBack me sale el código  mas sencillo y lo puedo mezclar con HTML.

Comment: He estado haciendo pruebas según el enlace que agregastes de ayuda. Me hace el evento. Pero el diseño del botón lo creo tambien dinamicamente no estáticamente por lo que el boton cuando lo renderiza me lo duplica por 2 veces 1 en el form ( este me hace el evento ) y otro en el que creo dinamicamente en el innerHtml ( Este boton si lo pulso no me hace evento ). Creando el evento dentro de OnInit con miBoton.ID = "btn01";  miForm.Controls.Add(miBoton); miBoton.Click += new System.Handler(miBoton_Click);

Answer (score 0):

Esta es la solución que me funciona, no he conseguido que el evento me salte a la función del servidor directamente pero si a una función a JavaScript en la cual puedo llamar a otra función en servidor.

En el archivo .aspx

```
<div id="miCodigo" runat="server">
</div>
```

En el archivo .aspx.cs

```
// Dentro del Page_Load
string contenido = "";
contenido += "<button id = 'btn" + id + "' type = 'button' class='boton' runat='server' onClick='miBoton_Click(\"idLlamada_" + id + "\")' />";
miCodigo.InnerHtml = contenido;
```

En el archivo JavaScript

```
function miBoton_Click(idLinea) {
   // Codigo en Javascript
   // Si lo necesito hago 'dopostback' aquí para llamar a función de servidor
}
```